# attempting to load images via webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to display an image in my React application using webpack, either via file-loader or url-loader. But so far I see only the file name, not the image.

Here's the relevant part of my webpack.config.js:

```
  ...
  {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
```

Here's the import at the top of my .jsx module:

`import MyImage from '../../../assets/images/library.png'`

And then in the render I have this:

`<div>{MyImage}</div>`

But for some reason the app shows the file name instead of the image.

Well, specifically, webpack first seems to change the name of the file to something different (f6273e549cbb9241d47952347b094df7.png), which appears next to the created bundle.js. But what renders on the page is that file name, as a literal string - rather than the actual image (lol). How can I show the image instead of that weird substitute file name?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the resulting image name will be `[contenthash].[ext]`, how [documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#name) outlines. Also, it's a good idea to put files into a separated folder:

```
{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/, use: [
        {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
                outputPath: 'img/'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In that way, you could keep things separated from each other(images, fonts, etc.). The proper usage is:

```
import MyImage from 'app/imgages/logo.png'
```

```
<div>
    <img src={MyImage} />
</div>
```